# How to search a CSV file based on an input field?

Tags: java, file, csv

I am able to access only few number of lines (41 lines to be proper).after that I am unable to read.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filePath = "qwe.csv";
        System.out.println("Enter the City name to be Searched\n");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);          
        String searchTerm = in.nextLine(); 
        readRecord(filePath, searchTerm);
    }

    public static void readRecord( String filePath, String searchTerm ) {

        boolean found = false;
        String City = ""; String City_Asciis = ""; String  Lattitude = "";
        String longitude = ""; String Country = "";
        String iso_2 = ""; String iso_3 = ""; String Admin_Name = "";
        String Capital = ""; String Population = ""; String Id = "";

        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            Scanner x = new Scanner (file);
            x.useDelimiter("[,\n]"); //to separate the data items 

            //hasNext - Returns true if the scanner has another token/value in its input

            while(x.hasNext() && !found) {

                City = x.next();
                City_Asciis = x.next();
                Lattitude = x.next();
                longitude = x.next();
                Country = x.next();
                iso_2 = x.next();
                iso_3 = x.next();
                Admin_Name = x.next();
                Capital = x.next();
                Population = x.next();
                Id = x.next();

                if (City.equals(searchTerm)) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }       

            if (found) {

                System.out.println(" The following details are of city : " + City +"\n The Ascii string would be : "
                    + City_Asciis +"\n Its having the lattitude around : "
                    + Lattitude + "\n and Longitude of : "+ longitude +"\n It is situated in : "
                    + Country +"\n These have iso code like  : "+ iso_2 +" and : "+ iso_3 +"\n It comes under  : "
                    + Admin_Name +" State \n Capital of this city is : "+ Capital +"\n The population is around : "
                    + Population +"\n ZIP code is : "+Id+"");
            }                       
            else {                      
                System.out.print("Enter the Correct City Name");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e1){
            System.out.print("file not found \n");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }       
}
```

This code will load the searched city from the file path given, so that given a particular city name print the details of the city.

Comment: Please configure your editor or IDE to format your code whenever you save it. Right now the code looks messier than it needs to.

Comment: Could you also provide the file you're reading?

Comment: You have to provide some sample data (two or three records) from the file you are using in the program.

Comment: It is convention in Java that one uses _camelCase_ (with first letter as lower-case) for specifying variable names. And, no underscores. For example, `City` and `Admin_Name` be named as `city` and `adminName` respectively.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions and answer, I have rectified my mistake,   the file had actually contained around 12,000 lines but it was reading only around 41 lines, the mistake I did was in  scanner I didn't mention which type of file it was ,`Scanner x = new Scanner (file,"UTF-8");`

Comment: the sample file consisted these type of data's city,city_ascii,lat,lng,country,iso2,iso3,admin_name,capital,population,id
Malishevë,Malisheve,42.4822,20.7458,Kosovo,XK,XKS,Malishevë,admin,,1901597212
Kamenicë,Kamenice,42.5781,21.5803,Kosovo,XK,XKS,Kamenicë,admin,,1901851592
Shtërpcë,Shterpce,42.2394,21.0272,Kosovo,XK,XKS,Shtërpcë,admin,,1901828239
Podujevë,Podujeve,42.9111,21.1899,Kosovo,XK,XKS,Podujevë,admin,,1901550082
Fushë Kosovë,Fushe Kosove,42.6639,21.0961,Kosovo,XK,XKS,Fushë Kosovë,admin,,1901134407
Kaçanik,Kacanik,42.2319,21.2594,Kosovo,XK,XKS,Kaçanik,admin,,1901200321

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who knows?

Without getting a headache, the code itself looks as though it should work and I personally can't off hand see why your read will only do 41 lines without doing a series of experiments with actual data and not many people really want to do that which is why you've been asked to provide some sample fictitious data.

It could be as simple as the fact that you are satisfying the boolean **found** variable criteria within the **while** loop condition and the loop breaks out stopping the read. I would suspect this since you do indicate that the `"code will load the searched city from the file path given"`. I should think that this is not really what you would want for the mere reason that some countries contain the same City names. As a matter of fact, some States, Provinces, or Regions within the same Country can contain same City names. As an example did you know that in the [United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_most_common_U.S._place_names) **alone**, there are **88** Cities and Towns named **Washington**? I know, weird right, especially when you consider that there are only 50 States and 2 Territories. *Benjamin Franklin* was also one of the Founding Fathers of the United States and there are **35** cities and towns/villages that honorably carry the name of **Franklin** within that country.

If your data file or database is big enough then I'm sure you would want to display all cities that match your specific search criteria. With that being said perhaps what you need to do is get rid of that `&& !found` condition for the **while** loop. I personally wouldn't use the [Scanner#hasNext()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext.htm) method in the **while** loop condition either. It's an invitation for disaster since it's more focused towards checking the availability of tokens when used in combination with [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) rather than actual file lines. Use the [**Scanner#hasNextLine()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextline.htm) in combination with the [**Scanner#nextLine()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method then use the [String#split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) method to parse the CSV comma (,) delimited data lines one line at a time.

Below I provide a runnable Java code example which demonstrates the above mentioned methods. Your **readRecord()** method is used but considerably modified to accommodate the following options:

- Return a List Interface (`List<String>`) of City information found
  pertaining to the supplied search criteria.
- Ignore (skip past) blank or comment lines within the CSV file. Comment lines can start with **#** or **;**.
- The option to ignore letter case during the search.
- Allow for selection of the desired City Information field to which
  the Search Criteria will be applied to. The City Information Fields
  are:

  City, CityAscii, Latitude, Longitude, Country, ISO2, 
    ISO3, AdminName, Capital, Population, and ID

  Wildcard (? and *) characters can be used when supplying the desired search field so that the entire field name does not need to be provided, for example: `lat*` for Latitude. So, you can do a City Information search simply based on population if you like instead of a City Name.
- Allow for wildcard (? and *) characters to be used within the
  supplied search criteria for example: `wash*`. This tells the method
  to search for any city which name starts with **Wash** like
  **Wash**ington or **Wash**ougal or **Wash**tucna.
- Allow for the number of found city instances to be returned.

Below is the runnable code which demonstrates the above mentioned concepts. The code is well commented. There are [Regular Expressions](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) used within the code and if you want an explanation of those expressions then copy/paste them into [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CityInfoRecords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* The appplication is started this way so that there
           is no need for static methods or variables.
        */
        new CityInfoRecords().startApp(args);
    }

    // Application Start method.
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        String ls = System.lineSeparator(); // Not all OS Consoles work well with "\n" 
        String filePath = "qwe.csv";        // Path and file name of the data file.
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Provide the City Info Field to base search from...
        System.out.println("Enter the Data Field you want to search by:" + ls
                + "[City, CityAscii, Lattitude, Longitude, Country" + ls
                + "ISO2, ISO3, AdminName, Capital, Population, ID]" + ls
                + "Wildcards (? and *) can be used:");
        String searchField = in.nextLine();

        // Provide the Search Criteria to find within the supplied City Info Field.
        System.out.println(ls + "Enter the search criteria you are looking for" + ls
                + "in " + searchField + ". Wildcards (? and *) are permitted:");
        String searchCriteria = in.nextLine();

        // Declare a List Interface of String and fill it 
        // with the call to the readRecord method.
        List<String> cityInfoList = readRecord(filePath, searchField, searchCriteria, 0, "N/A");

        // Display the returned List to console window.
        for (int i = 0; i < cityInfoList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(cityInfoList.get(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a List Interface of the City Information found based on the supplied 
     * search criteria.<br><br>
     * 
     * @param filePath (String) The full path and file name of the data file to read
     * containing City information.<br>
     * 
     * @param searchField (String) The City Information Field to based the supplied 
     * Search Criteria from. Any City Information Field can be supplied here and 
     * letter case is optional. The wildcard characters (? and *) can also be used 
     * here so that the entire field name does not need to be supplied, for example:
     * <pre>
     *          lat*    for the Latitude field or
     *          *asc*   for the CityAscii field or
     *          iso?    for either the ISO2 or ISO3 fields or simply
     *          City    for the City field.</pre><br>
     * 
     * The <b>?</b> wildcard character specifies any single alphanumeric character, 
     * as in ?an, which locates "ran," "pan", "can", and "ban".<br><br>
     * 
     * The <b>*</b> wildcard character specifies zero or more of any alphanumeric 
     * character, as in corp*, which locates "corp", "corporate", "corporation", 
     * "corporal", and "corpulent".<br> 
     * 
     * @param searchCriteria (String) The search criteria string. This can be any 
     * string you would like to search for within the supplied City Information 
     * Field. By default letter case is ignored during searches therefore the 
     * supplied search criteria string does not need to be letter case specific 
     * however if you want the search to be case specific then set this methods
     * optional ignoreLetterCase parameter to false.<br><br>
     * 
     * Wildcard characters (? and *) can also be used within the Search Criteria 
     * string so as to expand the search to other possibilities, for example if 
     * the "City" field is supplied and a criteria string like: "wash*" is supplied
     * then any city which name starts with "Wash" will have their city information 
     * returned.<br><br>
     * 
     * The <b>?</b> wildcard character specifies any single alphanumeric character, 
     * as in ?an, which locates "ran," "pan", "can", and "ban".<br><br>
     * 
     * The <b>*</b> wildcard character specifies zero or more of any alphanumeric 
     * character, as in corp*, which locates "corp", "corporate", "corporation", 
     * "corporal", and "corpulent".<br> 
     * 
     * @param numberOfFoundToReturn (int) The number of cities who's information 
     * should be returned. If 0 is supplied then all cities found will be returned.<br>
     * 
     * @param noDataReplacement (String) Sometimes there is no data supplied for a 
     * specific field within the data file or the file data line may not contain 
     * the same amount of delimited data. Rather than returning NULL or Null String 
     * ("") for empty data fields you can supply here what to actually return in 
     * such a case. "N/A" is a good choice or perhaps: "Nothing Supplied". Whatever 
     * you like to use can be supplied here.<br>
     * 
     * @param ignoreLetterCase (Optional - Boolean - Default is true) By default 
     * searches ignore letter case but if you want your search to be letter case 
     * specific then you can supply boolean false to this optional parameter.<br>
     * 
     * @return (String List Collection) Information for every City found within the 
     * supplied data file which matches the supplied field and search criteria.
     */
    public List<String> readRecord(String filePath, String searchField,
                            String searchCriteria, int numberOfFoundToReturn, 
                            String noDataReplacement, boolean... ignoreLetterCase) {
        String ls = System.lineSeparator(); // Not all OS Consoles work well with "\n" (property)
        boolean ignoreCase = true;          // Ignore letter case when searching (Default - property)
        if (ignoreLetterCase.length > 0) {
            ignoreCase = ignoreLetterCase[0];
        }
        boolean found = false;              // Flag to indicate data was found (toggles)
        int foundCounter = 0;               // Indicates number of same data found (increments)

        List<String> returnableList = // The List of found city information that will be returned (collection)
                new ArrayList<>();

        // City Information Variables (data fields)
        String city;
        String cityAscii;
        String latitude;
        String longitude;
        String country;
        String iso2;
        String iso3;
        String adminName;
        String capital;
        String population;
        String id;

        // Open Scanner to read data file...
        // Try With Resources is used here to auto close the reader.
        try (Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(filePath))) {
            // Iterate through data file...
            while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
                // Read file line by line and remove leading or 
                // trailing whitespaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.
                String cityData = fileReader.nextLine().trim();
                // Skip blank or comment lines (comment lines can be lines that start with # or ;)
                if (cityData.equals("") || cityData.startsWith("#") || cityData.startsWith(";")) {
                    continue;   // Get next file line
                }
                // Split the read line based on any comma delimited anomaly.
                String[] cityInfo = cityData.split(",|,\\s+|\\s+,|\\s+,\\s+");
                // The number of data pieces split from data line.
                // Not all lines may contain the same amount of data.
                int i = cityInfo.length;
                /* Ternary is used to fill city information variables
                   so that data not provided will not be null or null string.
                   As an Example for the city variabel this is the same as:
                        if (i >= 1 && !cityInfo[0].equals("")) {
                            city = cityInfo[0].trim();
                        }
                        else {
                            city = noDataReplacement;
                        }
                 */
                city = (i >= 1 && !cityInfo[0].equals("")) ? cityInfo[0].trim() : noDataReplacement;
                cityAscii = (i >= 2 && !cityInfo[1].equals("")) ? cityInfo[1].trim() : noDataReplacement;
                latitude = (i >= 3 && !cityInfo[2].equals("")) ? cityInfo[2].trim() : noDataReplacement;
                longitude = (i >= 4 && !cityInfo[3].equals("")) ? cityInfo[3].trim() : noDataReplacement;
                country = (i >= 5 && !cityInfo[4].equals("")) ? cityInfo[4].trim() : noDataReplacement;
                iso2 = (i >= 6 && !cityInfo[5].equals("")) ? cityInfo[5].trim() : noDataReplacement;
                iso3 = (i >= 7 && !cityInfo[6].equals("")) ? cityInfo[6].trim() : noDataReplacement;
                adminName = (i >= 8 && !cityInfo[7].equals("")) ? cityInfo[7].trim() : noDataReplacement;
                capital = (i >= 9 && !cityInfo[8].equals("")) ? cityInfo[8].trim() : noDataReplacement;
                population = (i >= 10 && !cityInfo[9].equals("")) ? cityInfo[9].trim() : noDataReplacement;
                id = (i >= 11 && !cityInfo[10].equals("")) ? cityInfo[10].trim() : noDataReplacement;

                // Determine the city data field we want to search in
                String regex;
                // Were wildcards used in the supplied Search Field string?
                if (searchField.contains("?") || searchField.contains("*")) {
                    // Yes... Prep regex to get proper search field
                    regex = searchField.replace("?", ".?").replace("*", ".*?").toLowerCase();
                }
                else {
                    regex = "(?i)(" + searchField + ")";
                }

                // Get proper search field data
                String field = "";
                if ("city".toLowerCase().matches(regex)) {
                    field = city;
                }
                else if ("cityAsciis".toLowerCase().matches(regex)) {
                    field = cityAscii;
                }
                else if ("lattitude".toLowerCase().matches(regex)) {
                    field = latitude;
                }
                else if ("longitude".toLowerCase().matches(regex)) {
                    field = longitude;
                }
                else if ("country".toLowerCase().matches(regex)) {
                    field = country;
                }
                else if ("iso2".toLowerCase().matches(regex)) {
                    field = iso2;
                }
                else if ("iso3".toLowerCase().matches(regex)) {
                    field = iso3;
                }
                else if ("adminName".toLowerCase().matches(regex)) {
                    field = adminName;
                }
                else if ("capital".toLowerCase().matches(regex)) {
                    field = capital;
                }
                else if ("population".toLowerCase().matches(regex)) {
                    field = population;
                }
                else if ("id".toLowerCase().matches(regex)) {
                    field = id;
                }
                if (field.equals("")) {
                    System.err.println("Invalid Search Field Name Provided! (" + searchField + ")");
                    return returnableList;
                }

                // See if the search criteria contains wildcard characters
                // A search can be carried out using wildcards in this method.
                if (searchCriteria.contains("?") || searchCriteria.contains("*")) {
                    // There is...build the required Regular Expression (RegEx) to use.
                    regex = searchCriteria.replace("?", ".?").replace("*", ".*?");
                    // See if the data item matches the search criteria ignoring letter case if desired.
                    // The String.matches() method is used for this and ternary for ignoring letter case.
                    if (ignoreCase ? field.toLowerCase().matches(regex.toLowerCase()) : field.matches(regex)) {
                        found = true;   // toogle flag to true if there is a match.
                    }
                }
                // No wildcard characters in search criteria...
                // Ternary is used in condition to handle ignore letter case if desired.
                else if (ignoreCase ? field.equalsIgnoreCase(searchCriteria) : field.equals(searchCriteria)) {
                    found = true;   // toogle flag to true if there is a match.
                }
                // If the 'found' flag has been set to true...
                if (found) {
                    // Add City information to returnable ArrayList
                    String info = ls + "The following details are of city: " + city + ls
                            + "The Ascii string would be: " + cityAscii + ls
                            + "It has the approximate Lattitude of: " + latitude + ls
                            + "And the approximate Longitude of: " + longitude + ls
                            + "It is situated in the country of: " + country + ls
                            + "The city has iso codes like: " + iso2 + " and: " + iso3 + ls
                            + "The State/Province/Region is: " + adminName + ls
                            + "Capital of this city is: " + capital + ls
                            + // Didn't know cities had capitals
                            "The population is approximately: " + population + ls
                            + "City general ZIP code is: " + id;
                    returnableList.add(info);   // Add to list
                    found = false;              // Toggle found flag back to false in prep to locate more city data.
                    foundCounter++;             // increment the found counter.

                    // If the First Instance Only flag is true then...
                    if (numberOfFoundToReturn > 0 && foundCounter == numberOfFoundToReturn) {
                        // Break out of the 'while' loop. We don't need anymore cities.
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // If the Found Counter was not incremented then
            // we didn't find any data in file... Inform User.
            if (foundCounter == 0) {
                System.err.print(ls + "Can not find City Name (" + searchCriteria
                        + ") in data file!" + ls);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.print("City Data file not found! (" + filePath + ")" + ls);
        }

        // Return the List of found data.
        return returnableList;
    }
}
```

Create a new Java Application Project and name it **CityInfoRecords**. Copy and paste the above code over top of the Main Startup class. Run the application, read the console prompts carefully and enter the proper data.

The first prompt asks for a City Information Field name...enter:  `city`.
The second prompt will ask for the search criteria for `city`...enter a city name in Upper or lower case (it doesn't matter). The city information will be displayed in console but only if that city name is contained within the City field within the data file.

Now run the code again and enter the same data except this time, for the city name just provide the first three letters of a city name and an asterisk (*) and then hit the enter key. Now any city information within your specific City Data File which starts with those supplied three letters will be displayed within the Console Window.

Play with it, try different fields to search from and play with the wildcard characters as well with your supplied field or search criteria data.

Now make **readRecord** a Class instead of a method which would be better.